# Dafny: How to handle reads clause in recursive function that traverses linked list

Tags: recursion, dafny

I'm trying to write a function, `list_corresponds` beneath,  to apply `corresponds` to the linked list `l` while moving through the string `s` it is given. How does one deal with the fact that the `reads` clause is leading to an error in the recursive call?

```
datatype TokenType =
    TokenNumber |
    TokenPlus   |
    TokenMinus  |
    TokenTimes  |
    TokenDivide |
    TokenLbrac  |
    TokenRbrac  |
    TokenError

class Token
{
    var c: char;
    var typ: TokenType;
    constructor (cc: char, t: TokenType)
        ensures c == cc && t == typ
    { 
        c := cc; typ := t; 
    }
}

predicate corresponds(c: char, token: Token)
    reads token
{
    c == token.c && (
        (token.typ == TokenNumber && '0' <= c && c <= '9') ||
        (token.typ == TokenPlus   && c == '+') ||
        (token.typ == TokenMinus  && c == '-') ||
        (token.typ == TokenTimes  && c == '*') ||
        (token.typ == TokenDivide && c == '/') ||
        (token.typ == TokenLbrac  && c == '(') ||
        (token.typ == TokenRbrac  && c == ')')
    )
}

class TokenList
{
    var tk: Token;
    var next: TokenList;
    var eol: bool;
    constructor (token: Token, l: TokenList, end: bool)
        ensures tk == token && next == l && eol == end
    {
        tk := token; next := l; eol := end;
    }
}

predicate list_corresponds(s: string, l: TokenList)
    reads l, l.tk
    decreases s
{
    if |s| == 0 then
        l.eol
    else
        assert |s| > 0;
        if s[0] == ' ' then
            false
        else
            corresponds(s[0], l.tk) && list_corresponds(s[1..], l.next)
}
```

The error (`Error: insufficient reads clause to invoke function`) is coming on the recursive invocation

```
list_corresponds(s[1..], l.next)
```

I've tried using a nullable type `TokenList?` for the argument `l` and the field `next` but this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `list_corresponds`, reads clauses say that it will read `l, l.lk` but when `l.next` is not null it will invoke `list_corresponds` on `l.next` there program will be reading `l.next` and `l.next.tk`. But you haven't mentioned `l.next.tk` in reads clause of parent call. Now problem is clear but solution might not be list out `l.next.tk` as it might go through another recursive call and you can't statically know how many recursion it will take. Further it will be different for different input.

There is standard approach to attack this problem in Dafny - by defining `ghost Repr` set which tracks all allocated object reachable through present object and saying anything in `Repr` is readable by method. Further we need `Class` constructed to be sound (devoid of cyclic reference) and this is done by defining `Valid()` predicate. For this case solution will look like

```
datatype TokenType =
    TokenNumber |
    TokenPlus   |
    TokenMinus  |
    TokenTimes  |
    TokenDivide |
    TokenLbrac  |
    TokenRbrac  |
    TokenError

class Token
{
    var c: char;
    var typ: TokenType;

    constructor (cc: char, t: TokenType)
        ensures c == cc && t == typ
    { 
        c := cc; typ := t; 
    }
}

predicate corresponds(c: char, token: Token)
    reads token
{
    c == token.c && (
        (token.typ == TokenNumber && '0' <= c && c <= '9') ||
        (token.typ == TokenPlus   && c == '+') ||
        (token.typ == TokenMinus  && c == '-') ||
        (token.typ == TokenTimes  && c == '*') ||
        (token.typ == TokenDivide && c == '/') ||
        (token.typ == TokenLbrac  && c == '(') ||
        (token.typ == TokenRbrac  && c == ')')
    )
}

class TokenList
{
    var tk: Token;
    var next: TokenList?;

    ghost var Repr : set<object>

    ghost predicate Valid()
      reads this, Repr
      ensures Valid() ==> this in Repr && this.tk in Repr
    {
        this in Repr && this.tk in Repr &&
        (next != null ==> (next in Repr && next.Repr <= Repr
           && this !in next.Repr && next.Valid()))
    }

    constructor (token: Token, l: TokenList?)
        requires l != null ==> l.Valid()
        ensures tk == token && next == l
        ensures Valid()
    {
        tk := token; next := l;
        Repr := {this, this.tk };
        if l != null {
            Repr := Repr + l.Repr;
        }
    }
}

predicate list_corresponds(s: string, l: TokenList?)
    requires (l != null ==> l.Valid())
    reads l , if l != null then l.Repr else {}
    decreases s
{
    if |s| == 0 && l == null then
        true
    else if |s| == 0 then false
    else if l == null then false
    else
        assert |s| > 0;
        if s[0] == ' ' then
            false
        else
            corresponds(s[0], l.tk) && list_corresponds(s[1..], l.next)
}
```

Comment: This make sense. However, if I delete the ensures line for the ghost predicate `Valid()`, the code still verifies, which suggests to me that the internal structure of `Valid()` is being used in the reasoning in `list_corresponds`. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is true. function by default are not opaque. predicate is function with boolean return value. So Dafny looks inside / reason with  such definition.